# Tell PyCharm debugger to not enter into decorators

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using my own decorators in many places in my code (e.g. for logging etc.). Is there a way to tell debugger to skip the decorator body and directly enter into the decorated function?

Comment: Don't put break points into the decorator, or use Run to cursor

Comment: I think I did not explain it clear. Suppose I am debugging inside function `A()` which calls function `B()` which is decorated. When I do 'step into function' on the line calling `B()` I do not get into `B()` but I do get into the decorator (which I am definitely not interested in - it only does some logging in my case). I just was curios if I could somehow skip this step and go directly into `B()`.

Comment: I don't think you can actually do that, using the Step-Into method. As far as Python is concerned, it has no idea that your function is decorated. The `@decorator` syntax is literally the same thing as `my_func = decorator(my_func)`, and so the debugger is indeed going to step into the `decorator()`'s code, since that's what's being invoked. What you *can* do is place a breakpoint inside of the decorated function; or else step into the decorator, and *then* step into the decorated function (`B()`) once you're inside the decorator.

Answer (score 2):

In settings you can specify which Python scripts the debugger should not step into.

Preferences -> Build, Execution Deployment -> Debugger -> Stepping -> Python (Should be at the very bottom).

Just tick the "Do not step into scripts" box, and specify the scripts you want.

[image: Here's a picture of my example for IntelliJ on macOS]

Comment: I am afraid this does not work for me. I assume the 'script' means the name of the file into which it should not step. But anyway, when I press 'Step into' in my debugger, it steps into the file containing the decorator definition event though I listed this file as the one to skip.

Comment: This is exactly the problem i was facing, try changing the pattern for the file name, my original file name was debug_utils.py and the pattern I chose was \*debug_utils\* (check out the image)

Comment: Using *<modulename>* half works for me - step into is suppressed on the way in but it steps into decorator whilst returning from the wrapped function. Also magic methods break it and it doesn't step into the wrapped function at all.